# How can We hide scrollbar for elementor popuups?

Tags: wordpress, popup, scrollbar, elementor

I want to hide scrollbars for Elementor popup on my website. How can I achieve this? I tried adding custom CSS and JS based on different answers such as  overflow: hidden

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCS0T.png)

Answer (score 1):

**You can try to navigate to the option "Overflow" in the items settings and change to "Hidden"** or use this code:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

If you want to allow scrolling but remove the bar, use css:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE and Edge */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```